# log in in all browsers with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, authentication

There is problem I cant resolve for 2 days. I need to login in many browsers in many machines on same sites. Its time-consuming task so I decide to do it with Selenium. I think problem is that while running test selenium does not save cookies. I find that its real to save cookies in file and then open them in next selenium tests but i need all browsers are logged in for manual testing. Here is my code

```
package automationFramework;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class FirstTestCase {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    File profileDirectory = new File(
            "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\n8a2y7sp.default");//path to firefox profile
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    baseUrl = "http://facebook.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void testVk() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(""); // login   
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(""); //password
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define **all browsers**. Do you mean many instances of same browser?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean? Do you try to achieve multiple browsers that access the same site simultaneously? If so, you will need to set up more than one driver instance.

If you'd like to achieve it sequentially, just use a loop where you open the driver and get the URL, do your thing, then kill the driver instance, repeat.

Comment: i know that I need to set up more than one driver instance. But at first i want to do it in ff. I want user stay logged in in browser after running selenium test

Comment: Then you should just use a loop where you open the driver and get the URL, do your thing, then kill the driver instance, repeat.